# Python/R ctypes library error: "OSError: lib/libRrefblas.so: undefined symbol: xerbla_"

Tags: r, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Firstly, I'm a newbie R, AWS and python guy. So I'm trying to get a python script with embedded R code running in AWS Lambda using rpy2. I created a Lambda package on an EC2 instance following the instructions [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/analyzing-genomics-data-at-scale-using-r-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/) (modified for using python 3.4). It seems that there is something funky happening with loading the R libs using ctypes, as per the following error received in the console:

*OSError: lib/libRrefblas.so: undefined symbol: xerbla_*

The test file (py_test.py) looks like this:

```
import os
import ctypes

for file in os.listdir('lib'):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join('lib', file)):
        ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(os.path.join('lib', file))

os.environ["R_HOME"] = os.getcwd()
os.environ["R_USER"] = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'rpy2')
os.environ["R_LIBS"] = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'library')
os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'lib')

import sys  
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'rpy2'))

import rpy2
from rpy2 import robjects

def test_handler(event, context):
    robjects.r('''
        f <- function(r, verbose=FALSE) {
            if (verbose) {
                cat("I am calling f().\n")
            }
            2 * pi * r
        }
        print(f(3))
        ''')

test_handler(None,None)
```

I have *lib/libRrefblas.so* in my virtual environment.  I have scoured google looking for answers but have come up empty. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the traceback, that could help, but I suspect the problem is that it's looking for xerbla_ in the wrong place. Is xerbla_ defined in the path to RLIBS? Maybe in libR.so?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the BLAS that ships with R is corrupt.  Your best bet is to make sure that BLAS and Lapack are installed on the machine you are building R on and see if you can get it to build with those libraries instead.

So steps would be to uninstall R, then run

```
yum -y install lapack-devel.x86_64 lapack.x86_64
yum -y install blas -devel
yum -y install R.x86_64
```

Check to see if it has still installed with libRrefblas.so.  *If* it has - try deleting that file and see if it will default to the system BLAS.  If you get a error because it is still looking for libRrefblas.so

```
rm lib/libRrefblas.so
cp /usr/lib64/libblas.so.3 lib/
mv lib/libblas.so.3 lib/libRrefblas.so
```